# Loading large div content with jquery ajax call. Accordions inside of div loaded are not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, accordion

I have one accordion inside of each section loaded (only one section shows at a time). All accordions have different ids, none are working.

```
$("#accordion1").accordion({
header: "h4", active: false, collapsible: true 
});

$("#accordion2").accordion({
header: "h4", active: false, collapsible: true 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get sure that your JavaScript gets executed, when your content is loaded via AJAX.

A recommendation is to wrap your functions inside the famous `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$(function(){
    $('#accordion1').accordion({});
});

$(function(){
    $('#accordion2').accordion({});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I'd guess that you're doing something like this:

```
$("#accordion1").accordion({
    header: "h4", active: false, collapsible: true 
});
$("#accordion2").accordion({
    header: "h4", active: false, collapsible: true 
});

// And later on...
$('#section').load('/gimme/accordion1');
```

And the stuff that you're loading from `/gimme/accordion1` contains `#accordion1`. That won't work because `$('#accordion1')` looks at the DOM when it is called and doesn't find an `#accordion1` to bind anything to; the later, when you load `#accordion1` into the DOM, it won't have an accordion bound to it because your `$('#accordion1').accordion(/*...*/)` call was done before there was an `#accordion1`.

You have to hook up the accordion widget when the accordion's HTML is in the DOM. Whatever function you're using to load your HTML should have a callback function that is called when the HTML is loaded so you can use that to hook up your widgets; for example, if you're using [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load):

```
$('#section').load('/gimme/accordion1', function() {
    $("#accordion1").accordion({
        header: "h4", active: false, collapsible: true 
    });
});
```